# Air conditioning compressor

Tags: chevrolet, ac, s10

Can I remove the non working a/c compressor from my '85 Chevy S 10 Pu truck? It is not working and I want to get it out of the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove it. Not knowing which engine you have in your vehicle, it's hard to tell you exactly what you'll need. Some engines, depending on the AC placement, will just require a shorter belt. Others will need a separate idler pulley which you put in place of the AC compressor. All it does it takes up the slack.

Conversely, if you aren't too worried about the AC compressor and are just wanting to remove it, you may consider just leaving it in place. While the pulley on the AC does not create a lot of parasitic drag on the fan belt, because it is just free wheeling the pulley. It would act pretty much like what an idler pulley does if you need to put one back in the compressors place.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have a 2.8 v 6 and the compressor is not hooked to anything. I am trying to replace the fuel line from the carb to the pump and it is in the way. I do not need it and was wondering if I could take it off my truck. Also the hoses for the compressor, can they just be cut loose?

Comment: If there is refrigerant still in the lines (R-12??), you need to have this evacuated prior to removing the lines. If you break something loose and there is still refrigerant in the lines, it can cause frost bite. Also, the R12 is not good for the Ozone layer. You can test this by pressing the inside of one of the two (high side/low side) Schraeder valves with a screwdriver tip. If anything comes out, get it evacuated at an AC shop. If nothing comes out, don't worry about it ... the damage is already done and no fear of getting bit.

Comment: It looks as though the AC may even be on a separate belt than the power steering pump and alternator, which would make this even easier. If it is on a single serpentine belt, you'll just need to get a shorter belt (look at the one for the 2.8 without AC and it should be right).

Comment: thanks. need to replace the fuel line also, from the pump to the carb. anything I can use besides the steel line it has now?